# Uploading captures video(using cordova capture plugin) to server

Tags: cordova, video

I am working on **cordova** application in which i need to capture video or choose from gallery and upload it to the remote server.
I have captured the video and it path is coming but can not able to send it to server.

```
$scope.takeVideo = function() {

        var options = {
            limit: 1
        };
        navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, options);

        // capture error callback
        var captureError = function(error) {
            navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
        };

        function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
            var i, path, len;
            /*for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
                alert(path);
            }*/
            path = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;
        };

        function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
            var ft = new FileTransfer(),
                path = mediaFile.fullPath,
                name = mediaFile.name;

            ft.upload(path,
                "http://127.0.0.1/uploadVideo",
                function(result) {
                    console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                    console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
                },
                { fileName: name });
        }
    }
```

**function uploadFile** is something i found in cordova site used for uploading but can not gettting the server side code how to do that, i searched but cannot find any appropriate example.

Comment: Even I had problem uploading images.... It never worked unless I used form submit with input type file button. Still, camera images can't be loaded... Never tried videos though.

Comment: i have done that successfully..if you still have problem i can post the answer here.

Comment: Please  share your code. Thanks